# Get selected feature names TFIDF Vectorizer

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp

I'm using python and I want to get the TFIDF representation for a large corpus of data, I'm using the following code to convert the docs into their TFIDF form.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(
    min_df=1,  # min count for relevant vocabulary
    max_features=4000,  # maximum number of features
    strip_accents='unicode',  # replace all accented unicode char 
    # by their corresponding  ASCII char
    analyzer='word',  # features made of words
    token_pattern=r'\w{1,}',  # tokenize only words of 4+ chars
    ngram_range=(1, 1),  # features made of a single tokens
    use_idf=True,  # enable inverse-document-frequency reweighting
    smooth_idf=True,  # prevents zero division for unseen words
    sublinear_tf=False)

tfidf_df = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(df['text'])
```

Here I pass a parameter `max_features`. The vectorizer will select the best features and return a scipy sparse matrix. Problem is I dont know which features are getting selected and how do I map those feature names back to the scipy matrix I get? Basically for the `n` selected features from the `m` number of documents, I want a `m x n` matrix with the selected features as the column names instead of their integer ids. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use [`tfidf_vectorizer.get_feature_names()`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.get_feature_names). This will print feature names selected (terms selected) from the raw documents.

You can also use `tfidf_vectorizer.vocabulary_` attribute to get a dict which will map the feature names to their indices, but will not be sorted. The array from `get_feature_names()` will be sorted by index.

Comment: The `vocabulary_` attribute is for the vectorizer not the transformed matrix.

Comment: does get_feature_names() has any parameter so that we could have just a glimpse?

Comment: @InsParbo What kind of glimpse? get_feature_names() will return an array of words used in vocabulary.

Comment: @VivekKumar like showing only few results of the total array.

Comment: @InsParbo You can use slicing on arrays like `arr[:5]`  to show top 5 values. Its just an array, view it as you want.

Answer (score 6):

use `tfidf_vectorizer.vocabulary_`, this gives a mapping from the features (terms back to the indices)

Comment: `tfidf_df.vocabulary_` gives me a attribute error. However I can get the features on using `tfidf_vectorizer.vocabulary_`, Is that what you meant?

Comment: yes I edited to reflect the change, but it look the using `get_feature_names()` is an even better solution.